# send dm to every user that reacted to a message in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a bot for my server and I want it to send a DM through a command with the subject to all users who reacted to the specific subject in a guide message.

E.G. !notify subject

my code currently looks like this:

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
  guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
    member.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#FF0000")
    .addField(" ", message.author)
    .addField("Subject", content)
    .setTimestamp()
    )

  })
})

  await message.channel.send(`${message.author} the message was successfully sent!`);
```

Comment: Please add a little bit more information about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing:
In your `guild.members.cache.forEach()`, you are referring to a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), then you use the `.send()` method. The issue is that a GuildMember does not have the send method, meaning you'd have to use a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

### Here's a fix:

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
  guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
    member.user.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed() // This is where the issue was located
    .setColor("#FF0000")
    .addField(" ", message.author)
    .addField("Subject", content)
    .setTimestamp()
    )

  })
})

  await message.channel.send(`${message.author} the message was successfully sent!`);
```